# How to give css when span tag within double quotes

Tags: php, html, css

I have something like this

```
<?php 
for ($i = 1;$i<=$review->rating;$i++) {
    print "<span class = "review-span" >★</span>";
}
?>
<style>
.review-span{
    color: #FFFF00;
}
</style>
```

It gives a syntax error saying syntax error,unexpected 'review' (T_STRING)
how to fix this error?can Anybody help me?

Comment: Put it in SINGLE QUOTES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, put it in single quotes

```
<?php 
for ($i = 1;$i<=$review->rating;$i++) {
    print '<span class="review-span">★</span>';
}
?>
```

Comment: If i need to make those stars big i can add <h2></h2> etc. tags . but when i add them it comes in vertically why it is happen and i have added these div tags around them also. <div style="width: 500px;height: 100px;float:left;">

Comment: So why do we not see a green tick here?

Comment: Riggs, Just for my information is there reasoning behind this? why are double quotes a syntax error? *in this situation*

Comment: Because you cannot put a double quoted string in a double quoted string, as the second `"` terminates the original double quoted string, _without adding escapeing characters which makes it almost unreadable and nearly impossible to debug_ So the simplest solution is to wrap the outer sting in single quotes, therefore making the inner double quoted string legal.

Comment: @mad_ss *"Thank you :-) you solved my problem"* so accept Riggs' answer. Asking another question is just that; another question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried to green tick but it was at the time he was posted this,then a message appears saying "You can accept answer only after 13 minutes. So after that now i saw this, that's why

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to escape the quotations by putting a backslash infront of it, if you are bound on using double quotes.

```
<?php 
for ($i = 1;$i<=$review->rating;$i++) {
    print "<span class = \"review-span\" >★</span>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thats fine but eventually when the strings get a bit more complicated it leads to totally unreadable code that you just cannot amend without making mistakes. I have worked on other peoples code with complex string done this way and it is a maintenace _Nightmare_